# QGIS Raster Symbology Gradient with Exceptions

Tags: qgis, symbology

I'm new to GIS. If I have a raster with a band of continuous numbers, say 0-1000 with decimals. I want that to be on some type of grey gradient.

However, I'm doing a lot of testing and want to be able to see particular values highlighted. For example, 0-1000 continuous can be on a grey gradient but I want to make specific exceptions where any pixel with the value of 400 is red and value of 600 is blue for easier visibility. Is this possible/simple to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a DEM with a range of values from 1 to 2128 that you style with a topographic color ramp like this:

[image]

You can now duplicate the layer and set another color ramp that you manually edit: set three markers (delete the others). First and last marker are completely transparent, the middle one is red. Set the interpolation to `discrete`. Than set the min/max settings to the values you like: from 500 to 600 in my case:

[image]

You can repeat this for other values. If you than turn on visibility for all layer, you get something like that:

[image]